# Variables de session en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Hola amigos estoy usando asp net core y quiero guardar datos en mis variables de sessión, llevo un rato intentando esto, pero marca un error en **Session**

> The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

este es mi método.

```
 public IActionResult LoginPost(LoginInfo paramsForm)
    {
        var mailx = paramsForm.email;
        var passx = paramsForm.pass;

        //Session["email"] = mailx;

        // HttpContext.Session.SetString("email_user", mailx);

        Session["Email"] = mailx; // <- aquí aparece


            return View("Test");
    }
```

StartUp

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {          

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recuperar los valores de `Session` debes usar los métodos de extensión especificados en `ISession`. Ver [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Ejemplo

```
var email = HttpContext.Session.GetString(EmailSessionKey);
```

Answer (score 3):

Si analizamos la documentacion

[Estado de sesión y aplicación en ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

en el titulo `Configurar el estado de sesión` veras que tienes que habilitar el uso de `session`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        // Make the session cookie essential
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });

}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();
}
```

Comment: si si tengo esto, pero me rechaza aún, ahorita actualizo mi pregunta

Comment: listo ya la actualicé

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad [session](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8) en estas condiciones:

1. Una forma Web que tenga acceso a la propiedad Page.Session
2. Una clase que tenga acceso a la propiedad HttpContext.Current

> ACTUALIZACION

En tu caso el código debería ser así:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Email"] = mailx;
```

Comment: HttpContext no contiene definicion para Current, dice mi error si pruebo esto

Comment: dice que httpcontext no existe en System.web